# Assign IPv6 addresses to kvm virtual machines using DHCP

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ipv6, dnsmasq

I created a bridge using `brctl` called `dhcp_test_br`, and bind my new created kvm virtual machine to this bridge.

Then I ran `dnsmasq`:

```
dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --interface=dhcp_test_br --except-interface lo --enable-ra --dhcp-range=2100:100::3,2100:100::4ff,slaac
```

I captured packets from both side, and found that such packets:

```
fe80::d489:56ff:fea1:67d3 > ip6-allnodes: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener querymax resp delay: 1000 addr: ::, length 24
fe80::d489:56ff:fea1:67d3 > ff02::1:ff00:1: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener reportmax resp delay: 0 addr: ff02::1:ff00:1, length 24
fe80::d489:56ff:fea1:67d3 > ff05::1:3: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener reportmax resp delay: 0 addr: ff05::1:3, length 24
fe80::d489:56ff:fea1:67d3 > ff02::1:2: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener reportmax resp delay: 0 addr: ff02::1:2, length 24
fe80::d489:56ff:fea1:67d3 > ip6-allrouters: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener reportmax resp delay: 0 addr: ip6-allrouters, length 24
fe80::d489:56ff:fea1:67d3 > ff02::1:ffa1:67d3: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener reportmax resp delay: 0 addr: ff02::1:ffa1:67d3, length 24
```

cannot be found on the virtual machine.(`fe80::d489:56ff:fea1:67d3`is the address of the bridge)

So how could I solve this and assign IPv6 addresses properly?

**Update:** changed the IPv6 range from 10:xx to 2100:xx, seems no difference

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to use a valid IPv6 address range.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What do you mean by valid? You may try a higher version of dnsmasq. The default version on Ubuntu doesn't work.

Comment: Valid, as in valid public (or unique-local) address. Public addresses start with 001 (binary), so these are 2xxx:: and 3xxx:: addresses

Comment: Your dhcpd configuration would be nice.  That said, you should avoid using DHCP to assign addresses in ipv6.  Servers which require a static IP should have this configured, and others should use route advertisements and self-assign an address.  You can still use DHCPv6 to provide configuration details like DNS servers and do DNS autoupdate.